# How do I get the caller's IP address in a WebMethod?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

How do I get the caller's IP address in a WebMethod?

```
[WebMethod]
public void Foo()
{
    // HttpRequest... ? - Not giving me any options through intellisense...
}
```

using C# and ASP.NET

Answer (score 86, accepted):

[HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress.aspx) is what you want.

Comment: If you get System.InvalidOperationException "HttpContext is not available.   This class can only be used in the context of an ASP.NET request." 
HttpContext in Context will not be available without adding some things to the web.config. 
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />. 
<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)>

Answer (score 9):

Just a caution. IP addresses can't be used to uniquely identify clients. NAT Firewalls and corporate proxies are everywhere, and hide many users behind a single IP.

Comment: Plus all HTTP headers can be spoofed easily. The same code that puts valid data in them can be used to put invalid data in them.

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
Context.Request.UserHostAddress
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
string ipAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

Haven't tried it in a webMethod, but I use it in standard HttpRequests

Answer (score 2):

The HttpContext is actually available inside the `WebService` base class, so just use `Context.Request` (or `HttpContext.Current` which also points to the current context) to get access to the members provided by the `HttpRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

I made the following function:

```
static public string sGetIP()
{
    try
    {
        string functionReturnValue = null;

        String oRequestHttp =
            WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers["User-Host-Address"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oRequestHttp))
        {
            OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;
            MessageProperties prop = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
            RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endpoint =
                prop[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
            oRequestHttp = endpoint.Address;
        }
        return functionReturnValue;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "unknown IP";
        }
}
```

This work only in Intranet, if you have some Proxy or natting you should study if the original IP is moved somewhere else in the http packet.