# How to retrieve IP of client which has make request to C# webservice

Tags: c#, web-services

i have created C# web service. i don't want everyone to call my webservice. i think getting ip i can protect to execute some methods. can anyone tell me way to protect Webservice with ip or another way

Comment: IP Addresses can be faked. So don't use **only** IP protection if you want to be 100% certain that your service is protected.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the caller's IP address in a WebMethod?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130328/how-do-i-get-the-callers-ip-address-in-a-webmethod)

Answer (score 5):

In a web service it is:

```
Context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

From an ASPX page you can get it with:

```
Request.UserHostAddress();
```

Update:
That could be empty because of a proxy etc.. Add these two classes to increase your chances to get a proper IP back. Just a warning.. Those headers are very easy to manipulate and are not 100% for security. (As a note I got this code from somewhere but can remember the source..)

```
    public string DetermineIP(HttpContext context)
{
  if (context.Request.ServerVariables.AllKeys.Contains("HTTP_CLIENT_IP") && CheckIP(context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]))
    return context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];
 
  if (context.Request.ServerVariables.AllKeys.Contains("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"))
    foreach (string ip in context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].Split(','))
      if (CheckIP(ip.Trim()))
        return ip.Trim();
 
  if (context.Request.ServerVariables.AllKeys.Contains("HTTP_X_FORWARDED") && CheckIP(context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"]))
    return context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"];
 
  if (context.Request.ServerVariables.AllKeys.Contains("HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP") && CheckIP(context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP"]))
    return context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP"];
 
  if (context.Request.ServerVariables.AllKeys.Contains("HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR") && CheckIP(context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"]))
    return context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"];
 
  if (context.Request.ServerVariables.AllKeys.Contains("HTTP_FORWARDED") && CheckIP(context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_FORWARDED"]))
    return context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_FORWARDED"];
 
  return context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}

    private bool CheckIP(string ip)
{
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
  {
    long ipToLong = -1;
    //Is it valid IP address
    if (TryConvertIPToLong(ip, out ipToLong))
    {
      //Does it fall within a private network range
      foreach (long[] privateIp in _privateIps)
        if ((ipToLong >= privateIp[0]) && (ipToLong <= privateIp[1]))
          return false;
        return true;
    }
    else
      return false;
  }
  else
    return false;
}





private bool TryConvertIPToLong(string ip, out long ipToLong)
{
  try
  {
    ipToLong = ConvertIPToLong(ip);
    return true;
  }
  catch
  {
    ipToLong = -1;
    return false;
  }
}

private long ConvertIPToLong(string ip)
{
  string[] ipSplit = ip.Split('.');
  return (16777216L * Convert.ToInt32(ipSplit[0]) + 65536 * Convert.ToInt32(ipSplit[1]) + 256 * Convert.ToInt32(ipSplit[2]) + Convert.ToInt32(ipSplit[3])); 
}


    private long[][] _privateIps = new long[][] {
  new long[] {ConvertIPToLong("0.0.0.0"), ConvertIPToLong("2.255.255.255")},
  new long[] {ConvertIPToLong("10.0.0.0"), ConvertIPToLong("10.255.255.255")},
  new long[] {ConvertIPToLong("127.0.0.0"), ConvertIPToLong("127.255.255.255")},
  new long[] {ConvertIPToLong("169.254.0.0"), ConvertIPToLong("169.254.255.255")},
  new long[] {ConvertIPToLong("172.16.0.0"), ConvertIPToLong("172.31.255.255")},
  new long[] {ConvertIPToLong("192.0.2.0"), ConvertIPToLong("192.0.2.255")},
  new long[] {ConvertIPToLong("192.168.0.0"), ConvertIPToLong("192.168.255.255")},
  new long[] {ConvertIPToLong("255.255.255.0"), ConvertIPToLong("255.255.255.255")}
};
```

Comment: it returns somethink like ::1 not client ip

Comment: can not find _privateIps variable

Comment: Sorry forgot to copy that! I have added in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Grab the IP address from the request object `Request.UserHostAddress`

Then test to see if its equal to your allowed ip address, if it is serve content if not return a http 403 status code (IIS has 403.6 for IP address rejected if you want to give additional information)