# How to find the external IP from a desktop app. Note: not the local IP

Tags: windows, geolocation, ip, desktop-application

I am working on some legacy code on Windows for a desktop app in "C.
The client needs to know the geo-location of the user who is running the application.
I have the geo-location code all working (using MaxMind: `http://dev.maxmind.com/`).
But now I'm looking for help in getting their external IP.

From all the discussions on this topic throughout SO and elsewhere it seems that there is a way to do this by connecting to a "reliable" host (server) and then doing some kind of lookup. I'm not too savvy on WinSock but this is the technology that may be the simplest to use.
Another option is to use WinHttpConnect technology.
Both have "C" interfaces.

Thank you for your support and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a simple web service that checks the IP address(es) that the program presents when connecting to that web service.

Look at http://whatismyip.com for an example.

Note that multiple addresses can be presented by the HTTP protocol if there are proxy servers along the route.

You can design your simple web service to get the IP of the client.  See

[How do I get the caller's IP address in a WebMethod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130328/how-do-i-get-the-callers-ip-address-in-a-webmethod)

and then return that address back to the caller.

Note that in about 15% of cases (my experience metric) the geo location will be way off.  The classic example is that most AOL users are routed through a small number of proxy servers.  However, there are many other cases where the public IP does not match the user's actual location.  Additionally, Geo IP databases are sometimes just wrong.

**Edit**

It is not possible to detect your external IP address using only in-browser code.

The WebSocket has no provision to expose your external IP address.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455

You need an outside server to tell you what IP it sees.

Comment: I am actually looking for a solution that does not require server side work.I currently have test code that creates a socket and connects to a server (like Google or Yahoo). I would like to query that connection in some way to get back the external IP of my side of the connection.

Comment: That's too bad. I wonder how Windows Terminal does it when I use the 'tracert' command. It tracks all the "hops" and reveals my external IP.

Comment: C:\Users\William>tracert google.com
Tracing route to google.com [173.194.79.100]
over a maximum of 30 hops:  YOUNGPENGUIN [192.168.1.1] hsd1.ca.comcast.net [76.102.176.1] etc.

Comment: Windows Terminal has full access to the operating system.  Your code is running in a browser sandbox.  That sandbox intentionally hides a great deal of functionality from the browser as a security precaution.

Comment: Thank you. I am now focused on creating a server side application in rails that will return the client IP. That seems to be the way to go.

Comment: I used the free IP geo-location software from [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/en/geolite). I'm quite happy with that. I also wrote a mini app in rails to display the client server IP. And some simple WinHTTP code for desktop Windows apps to access the server page. It's all working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to help.  MaxMind is great for the money, but not as accurate as the high end (and *very* expensive alternatives).  Just be aware that it will be wrong sometimes.

Comment: My client only needs country level accuracy which MaxMind claims is over 99% accurate.

Comment: Keep in mind that people wishing to commit fraud will often have access to a proxy server in the US or other stable country.  Don't know if that is a consideration for you.

Comment: It is a consideration and I have seen some discussion on this topic. But I will leave that subject for another fresh question on SO.

Comment: Feel free to link to your new question from this one.